# How do I filter this object array using NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nspredicate

```
How do I filter this object array using NSPredicate filteredArrayUsingPredicate / predicateWithBlock?
```

Class `Person` is my modal class that has several properties like `firstName`, `lastName` etc.
each object of this class is stored in an array `objPersonCell`. And from my *view controller* I am  displaying fields on `UITableViewCell` using :

```
// way similar to this
        for(NSMutableArray *obj in self.objPersonCell){   
            lblFirstName.text = [(Person *)obj personType];
        }
```

**Problem :** For Search, I want user to type and filter objPersonCell using `NSPredicate` and immediately reflect the changes by reloading the data on UITableView. Now how do I use `NSPredicate`.

*What I have tried is :*

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        NSString *searchTerm = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        [self updateAsPerSearchTerm: searchTerm];

        return YES;
    }

-(void)updateAsPerSearchTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm
{

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains[cd] %@",searchTerm];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [[(Person *)self.objPersonCell] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    [self.objPersonCell removeAllObjects];
    [self.objPersonCell addObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The code inside `updateAsPerSearchTerm` is wrong for passing objPersonCell. How do I set it up. And How  `predicateWithBlock` would better help me out, if can ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about casting. This code:

```
for(NSMutableArray *obj in self.objPersonCell){   
    lblFirstName.text = [(Person *)obj personType];
}
```

should be

```
for (Person *obj in self.objPersonCell){   
    lblFirstName.text = [obj personType];
}
```

because the contents of the `objPersonCell` array are `Person` objects.

A similar problem is here:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [[(Person *)self.objPersonCell] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

where you should have

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [self.objPersonCell filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Now, on your filtering problem, you should have a couple of properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *objPersonCell;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *tableDataSource;
```

by default:

```
self.tableDataSource = self.objPersonCell;
```

when you do a search:

```
self.tableDataSource = sortedArray;
```

when you cancel / complete a search:

```
self.tableDataSource = self.objPersonCell;
```

In this way you are never editing `objPersonCell` while searching (and corrupting its contents) and your table data source methods remain simple as you aren't trying to switch between different source arrays. The table data source methods should use only `tableDataSource`, not `objPersonCell`.